# Indexing into an array of semaphores

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, semaphore

Lets say I initialized two global arrays of semaphores,

`semaphore empty[someNum];`

and

`semaphore full[someNum];`

and `someNum` is initialized as

`const int someNum = 3;` (globally)

I'll have a method called `init()` and inside is a `for-loop` to help index those arrays.

`for (index=0; index<someNum; index++) num[index]=0;`

my goal is to use commands like `wait` and `signal` certain semaphores in the array, for example if `num` is full, then I do not want my producer to place a value into it.

inside of `init()` I know that I need to initialize all the semaphores in the loop body. So far I have tried

`empty[index] = create_semaphore(1)`

`full[index] = create_semaphore(0)`

and inside of the methods I want to preform the actions `wait` and `signal` I tried for example

`wait(empty) ;`

but I get back errors. I know it is because I am using the name of the array and not a specific semaphore.

So my question is, how do I properly index into my arrays in my `for-loop` to specify one semaphore?

Thanks for any and all inputs! If you have any questions feel free to ask for any clarification! And please be patient with me, semaphores are a new concept to me.

**NOTE**

the command `create_semaphore` exists in another program affiliated with this one.

**EDIT**

**foodPass.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sched.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string>
#include "sem.h"

using namespace std ;

/* ######################################## */
/*             Misc Data Types              */
/* ######################################## */
     /* A data type - a struct with an int field
        to represent a child ID at the program level. */
struct threadIdType
{
  int id ;
};

/* ######################################## */
/*             Global Variables             */
/* ######################################## */
//const int numTrivets = 6 ;
const int numTrivets = 3 ;
const int numDiners = numTrivets - 1 ;
const int maxDishNames = 13 ;
//const int numDishNames = 13 ;
const int numDishNames = 5 ;

int trivet[numTrivets] ;

string dishName[maxDishNames];

      /* Here declare the semaphores and other variables you will
         need to synchronize threads. */

sim_semaphore  empty[numTrivets] ; 
sim_semaphore  full[numTrivets] ; 

      /* child_t are global variables to represent the
         dynamically-created threads. */

pthread_t child_t[numTrivets] ;

/* ######################################## */
/*      "Special"   Global Variables        */
/* ######################################## */

/* Code in sem.cpp "expects" the two variables below to be here.
   This particular program does not use "checking." */

         /* "Checking" is just a flag that you set to 1 if you want lots of
            debugging messages and set to 0 otherwise.  The semaphore code in
            sem.cpp imports "checking".  Therefore the semaphore operations
            will write lots of messages if you set checking=1.  */

int checking ;

      /* In some programs, we use the "stdoutLock" variable declared below to
         get intelligible printouts from multiple concurrent threads that write
         to the standard output.  (There has to be something to prevent the
         output of the threads from interleaving unintelligibly on the standard
         output, and we can't use semaphores if the semaphore code is writing
         messages too.)

         To print a message to standard output, a thread first locks standard
         output, then writes, then unlocks standard output.  See files sem.cpp
         or conc.cpp for examples of code that write messages in this manner.

         WARNING:  DON'T change how the locking of standard output is done
         until you've thought a WHOLE lot about the consequences.  In
         particular, using semaphores to do the job of stdoutLock can cause
         "infinite recursion" under certain circumstances.  The reason is that
         the semaphore code itself imports "stdoutLock" and writes messages
         when the "checking" variable is set to 1. */

pthread_mutex_t stdoutLock ;

/* ################################################## */
/*                         init                       */
/* ################################################## */
void init()
{
  int index ;

  srandom(time((time_t *) 0)); /* INITIALIZE RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR */

  checking = 0 ;

       /* Initialize the "special lock" that is used only to get
          exclusive access to the screen. */

  if ( 0!=pthread_mutex_init(&stdoutLock, NULL) )
  {  cout << "MUTEX INITIALIZATION FAILURE!" << endl;
     exit(-1) ;}

    /* Initialize the trivets to indicate that each contains "no
       dish." */

  for (index=0; index<numTrivets; index++) trivet[index]=0;

    /* Here initialize the semaphores and other variables you use
       for synchronization.  */

  for (index=0; index<numTrivets; index++) full[index] = create_sim_sem(0) ;
  for (index=0; index<numTrivets; index++) empty[index] = create_sim_sem(1) ;


 /* Give some mnemonic names to the dishes.  The first name is
    used for an empty trivet.  The last name denotes the check
    (bill) for the meal.  This is coded so no changes are needed
    here as long as the value of "numDishNames" is between 2 and
    13. */

  dishName[0]="no dish";
  dishName[1]="vegetable soup" ;
  dishName[2]="bread and butter" ;
  dishName[3]="beets and chickpeas" ;
  dishName[4]="hardboiled eggs" ;
  dishName[5]="calf tongue" ;
  dishName[6]="baked potato" ;
  dishName[7]="string beans" ;
  dishName[8]="rack of lamb" ;
  dishName[9]="salad" ;
  dishName[10]="coffee" ;
  dishName[11]="flan" ;
  dishName[numDishNames-1]="check" ;

}

/* ################################################## */
/*                    DelayAsMuchAs                   */
/* ################################################## */
void delayAsMuchAs (int limit)
{
  int time, step;
  time=(int)random()%limit;
  for (step=0;step<time;step++) sched_yield() ;
}

/* ################################################## */
/*                       Server                       */
/* ################################################## */
/*

     The mother thread spawns a child thread that executes this
     function.  This function carries out the job of the server
     at the restaurant.

*/
void * Server(void * ignore)
{
  int i, j, delayLimit=100 ;

  for (i=1; i<numDishNames; i++)
  {

        /* I delay a random time before I "feel like" placing
           another dish on the table.*/

    delayAsMuchAs(delayLimit);

      /* When the trivet is available, I place the dish on the
         trivet to my right. */

       /* Here do a synchronization task.  One thing you need to
          do is be sure that you are not going to place a dish on
          a trivet that alreay has a dish on it.  *DO NOT* just
          busy-wait until you see that the trivet is empty. */

    wait_sem(empty[i]) ; 

    trivet[0]=i; // put dish #i onto trivet #0
    pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
    cout << "Server places " << dishName[trivet[0]]
         << " on trivet #0." << endl ;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock);

       /* Here you may want to a synchronization task --
          something that "opens the door" for diner #0 to get
          access to the new dish. */

    signal_sem(full[i]) ; 


  }
  pthread_exit ((void *)0) ;
}

/* ################################################## */
/*                         Diner                      */
/* ################################################## */
/*

     The mother thread spawns child threads that execute this
     function.  This function carries out the job of one of the
     diners at the restaurant.

*/

void * Diner(void * postnPtr)
{
       /* Type cast the parameter to recover "position" -- which
          tells me the position at which I am seated at the
          table. */
int position = ((threadIdType *)(postnPtr))->id ;

  int i, j, delayLimit=100 ;

  for (i=1; i<numDishNames; i++)
  {
        /* I delay a random time before I "feel like" picking up the next
           dish.*/

    delayAsMuchAs(delayLimit);

      /* When available, I pick up the next new dish on my left. */

       /* Here do a synchronization task.  One thing you need to
          do is be sure that there is a new dish on the trivet to
          your left now, and that the person on your left has
          "let go" of it. */

    wait_sem(full[i]); 

      /* I declare what I am doing */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
    cout << "Diner number "<< position ;
    if (i<numDishNames-1) cout << " enjoys ";
    else if (position<numDiners-1) cout << " examines " ;
         else cout << " examines and pays " ;

    cout << dishName[trivet[position]] << endl ;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock);

        /* I delay a random time to simulate the time it takes for me to
           serve myself some of what is on the dish -- or look at the
           check. */

    delayAsMuchAs(delayLimit);

        /* When available, I place the dish on the trivet to my right. */

       /* Here do a synchronization task.  One thing you need to
          do is be sure that the trivet on your right does not
          have a dish on it now.*/

    wait_sem (empty[i]); 

    pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
    cout << "Diner number "<< position << " moves "
         << dishName[trivet[position]] << " from trivet #"
         << position << " to trivet #" << position+1 << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock);
       /* transfer the dish on my left to trivet on my right */
    trivet[position+1]=trivet[position] ;
      /* mark trivet on my left as empty */
    trivet[position]=0;

       /* Here do a synchronization task. You have transferred a
          dish from your left to your right.  The person on your
          left will need to find out that the trivet on your left
          is now empty.  The person on your right will need to
          find out that the trivet on your right now has a new
          dish on it.  */

    signal_sem(empty[i]); 
    signal_sem(full[i]); 

  }
  delete((threadIdType *)(postnPtr)) ;
  pthread_exit ((void *) 0) ;
}

/* ################################################## */
/*                       Busser                       */
/* ################################################## */
/*

     The mother thread spawns children and then executes this
     function.  This is convenient because this function should
     be the last to exit.  This function carries out the job of
     the busser at the restaurant.

*/
void * Busser (void * ignore)
{
  int i, j, delayLimit=100 ;

  for (i=1; i<numDishNames; i++)
  {
        /* I delay a random time before I "feel like" bussing another
           dish.*/

    delayAsMuchAs(delayLimit);

      /* When another dish is on the trivet to my right I remove it. */

       /* Here do a synchronization task.  One thing you need to
          do is be sure that there is a new dish on the trivet to
          your left now, and that the person on your left has
          "let go" of it. */

    wait_sem (full[i]) ; 

    pthread_mutex_lock(&stdoutLock) ;
    cout << "Busser removes "
         << dishName[trivet[numTrivets-1]] << " from trivet #"
         << numTrivets-1<< "." << endl ;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stdoutLock);
    trivet[numTrivets-1]=0; // remove the dish.

       /* Here do a synchronization task. The person on your left
          will need to find out that the trivet on your left is
          now empty.  */

    signal_sem (empty[i]); 
  }
  return ignore ;
}

/* ################################################## */
/*                         Main                       */
/* ################################################## */
int main()
{
    init();

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to the restaurant!" << endl ;
    cout << numDiners << " will be dining." << endl ;
    cout << "The meal will consist of " << numDishNames-2
         << " dishes." << endl;
    cout << "Bon appetite!" << endl ;
    cout << endl << endl;

    int i;

        /* This is a pointer to a struct that contains an int
          field - it is a convenient data type to use as the
          parameter to the child function.  */
    threadIdType * idPtr ;

    for (i=0; i<numDiners; i++)
    {
          /* This records the current index as this child's ID */
       idPtr = new threadIdType ;
       idPtr->id = i ;

       if (0!=pthread_create(&child_t[i], NULL, Diner, (void *) idPtr))
          {cout << "THREAD CREATION FAILURE!" << endl; exit(-1) ;}

       if (0!=pthread_detach(child_t[i]))
          {cout << "THREAD DETACHMENT FAILURE!" << endl ; exit(-1) ;}
    }

       if (0!=pthread_create(&child_t[numDiners], NULL, Server, (void *) 0))
          {cout << "THREAD CREATION FAILURE!" << endl; exit(-1) ;}

       if (0!=pthread_detach(child_t[numDiners]))
          {cout << "THREAD DETACHMENT FAILURE!" << endl ; exit(-1) ;}

    Busser((void *) 0) ;

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Thank you for coming!" << endl ;
    cout << endl << endl;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: What library are you using? If you want to wait on a specific semaphore then you'll have to give the index to it. I'm not sure that's what you want tho. POSIX semaphores are based on a counter so it's possible (if I understand you correctly) to do this with a single semaphore initialized to the correct values.

Comment: Ok, I added my libraries to my edit

Comment: Well, I think you know the answer to the immediate problem which is you can't pass an array as a sem. If you're sure you otherwise have the correct implementation then it's as simple as iterating over them and waiting on them individually. But those are blocking calls so I'm hesitant to suggest much more without seeing what  you're specifically doing.

Comment: I know the "answer" yes but how to do it is my question. I am a little stumped and my solution `full[index] = create_sem(0);` feels wrong but I don't know what to change it to. Also, if I don't put `wait(full);` as my command, what goes in place of `full`? I'm sorry if I'm not being resourceful my code is very lengthy I'm trying my best to provide as much info as I can, if you need anything more please ask.

Comment: If you're indexing an array of sems then it'd be `wait(full[i])` : `i` = the index you want. I think your feeling of it being wrong is right but it's not easy to tell. It may be correct but it depends on how it's used. Consider that a sem is telling you "this is how many can access a resource or critical section at a time." If you only want one then initialize it to 1. But if you want more than one then initialize it to `n`. When the sem decs to <= 0 no more procs will be able to access the resource/code.

Comment: When I suggested to my instructor my the above solution, he said it is wrong because I need to initialize ALL the semaphores by including them in the loop body. I'm not sure how to do this part

Comment: I think the best thing you can do is press them for further suggestions. Without the real code I can't offer any more help. I can only assume they mean exactly what I'm saying. You need an index to a sem in the array. How do you do that? You need a loop (probably a `for`).

Comment: ok I added my code to the edit, I hope it doesn't cause too much confusion. The current code gives back a segmentation fault.

Comment: `full[index]` and `empty[index]` are "elements" outside the respective arrays. As your instructor said, use a loop. (You've already been shown how to do it - look at the `trivet` initialization loop.)

Comment: Ok i updated my code because I understand a little bit better, however it still produces a 'segmentation fault'. Is there a misuse of a command? The program outputs the first two lines correctly before producing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out my problem.

Though I correctly initialized my index arrays in `init()`,

```
for (index=0; index<numTrivets; index++) full[index] = create_sim_sem(0) ;
for (index=0; index<numTrivets; index++) empty[index] = create_sim_sem(1) ;
```

My problem actually came from the `wait` and `signal` commands.

In `server()` is a pure producer and is only responsible for the first array index `0` so the commands are simply

`wait_sem(empty[0])` and `signal_sem(full[0])`

In `diner()` it is a little more complicated. It acts as a hybrid between producer and consumer, meaning we cannot just use `0` and `1`, so we look at how `trivet[]` indexed a single semaphore and borrow that, then we get

`wait_sem(full[position])`

furthermore, there are two positions the `diner()` has to worry about. So, we have to make the next position exclusive so we initialize `trivet[position+1]` and once again borrow that when we are dealing with `waits` and `signals` that are to their right.

Lastly, we have `busser()` who acts purely as a consumer. We only signal him when his spot is full for him to consume. Since the number of trivets are interchangeable, (`numTrivets`) we cannot simply put in `1` because there can be more than 2 spots next time. Therefore, we need only to put in commands like

`wait_sem(full[numTrivets-1])` and then `signal_sem(empty[numTrivets-1])`

and then I get my desired output.

Thank you to everyone who gave me input I hope my answer proves useful to all those who were confused like myself